# Custom Cursor in Highmaps when no data is available for hovered country

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts, highmaps

I'm using Highcharts with Highmaps to display country information. My world map is initialized as follows:

```
data.series[0].data = {...}; // array with 135 entries     
data.series[0].mapData = Highcharts.maps['custom/world']; // world map with 213 countries
data.series[0].point.events.click = function(){ //do something };
```

Everything is working fine, data is displayed and onClick handler is working too. To show users that countries are clickable, I set the cursor to be the hand icon:

```
data.plotOptions.series.cursor = "pointer";
```

Now the problem. Sometimes I don't have data for all countries, so the "empty" countries are not clickable. Highmaps does not fire an event when I click the country, but I also want to overwrite the cursor for those countries.

How can I set a custom cursor if no value exists for the given point?

*Highcharts v4.2.5*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

`plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOver` event

and

`plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOut` event.

```
plotOptions: {
         series: {
             point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function () {

                        $("#container").addClass("cursor");
                    },
                    mouseOut: function () {

                        $("#container").removeClass("cursor");
                    }
                }
            },
         }
}
```

by doing this no event triggers on areas that has no value.
you should also remove `plotOptions.series.cursor = "pointer";`

**[A Working Sample On Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsh85/zoedb0jp/1/)**